# CTE performance on execution plan. Is it displayed two times, or two times processed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization, common-table-expression

This is the SQL with CommonTableExpression. Note, that USERS_PROJECTS_CTE used twice.

```
 WITH USERS_PROJECTS_CTE (PRO_ID, SHOW_IAS, USERNAME)
   AS
   (
      SELECT up.PRO_ID, up.SHOW_IAS, ISNULL(u.FIRST_NAME, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(u.SECOND_NAME, '')
      FROM SFMIS07_PRO.USERS_PROJECTS up
      INNER JOIN SFMIS07_ADM.USERS  AS u 
                ON  up.USER_ID = u.ID
      WHERE up.IS_RESP_PERSON = 1 AND up.valid_to is null
   )
   SELECT up.PRO_ID, 
          up1.USERNAME as RESP_USER1,
          up2.USERNAME as RESP_USER2,
          up.COUNT_
   FROM SFMIS07_PRO.PRO_RESP_USERS_KERNEL_MV  AS up 
        LEFT JOIN USERS_PROJECTS_CTE  AS up1 ON up.PRO_ID = up1.PRO_ID AND up1.SHOW_IAS=1  
        LEFT JOIN USERS_PROJECTS_CTE  AS up2 ON up.PRO_ID = up2.PRO_ID AND up2.SHOW_IAS=0
```

The Execution Plan. Note that CTE displayed twice: 
[image]

Questions:

1. am I right that CTE is not only displayed twice but processed twice?
2. is it possible to inform QO to reuse CTE  ?
3. is it possible for QO in principle to detect "the same SQL fragment" and reuse results (I imagine the realization of this - by coping already prepared data)?
4. how to optimize the query  (without using temporal tables :) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I right that CTE is not only displayed twice but processed twice?

Yes

> Is it possible to inform QO to reuse CTE ?

Not directly but there are some hacks to encourage this.

> is it possible for QO in principle to detect "the same SQL fragment"
>   and reuse results (I imagine the realization of this - by coping
>   already prepared data)?

In principle yes. See Microsoft Research Paper [Efﬁcient Exploitation of Similar Subexpressions for Query
Processing](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1247540) for examples.

> how to optimize the query (without using temporal tables :) ?

The most reliable way would be to use a temporary (not temporal) table.  See [Provide a hint to force intermediate materialization of CTEs or derived tables](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32891374-provide-a-hint-to-force-intermediate-materializati) for a more hacky workaround.

Comment: Have you ever seen the QO deduplicate joins? I believe this feature is completely absent as of 2012.

Comment: @usr - Yes the stuff from that research paper has so far not made its way into the product at all AFAIK. I was just answering the "in principle" part. At the moment if you want intermediate materialization and can't do it explicitly yourself then you need to resort to things like the `TOP  (2147483647)` hack.

Comment: Just to append: hack "Top 2147483647" doesn't work with self-joins (as I undestand the principle)

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij - Yes. Just tried and see what you mean. I don't get a spool show up at all for `WITH T AS (SELECT TOP 2147483647 * FROM master..spt_values WHERE high%10 = 1 ORDER BY name) SELECT * FROM T T1 INNER JOIN T T2 ON T1.number = T2.number` for example.